# Start and Stop scripts buttons are hidden on instruments

Tags: instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I opened Instruments and select the Automation template for it.
After opening an Instrument tool i selected an app from Choose Target.
After that i selected my Java Script file from Choose script option but the Start Script and Stop Script option are not getting enabled.In this case how should i Record and Playback my Scripts in Instruments. I am using Xcode 4.1.
Please help me to enable those buttons and please guide me on how can i record and playback scripts on Insstruments.

Answer (score 0):

This might be iOS device/simulator incompatibility. Record is available for iOS 5 and above. If you will connect device with 4.x iOS or launch simulator for 4.x iOS - record will be disabled.